# Style input type="text"

Tags: html, forms, input

I have an `<input>`, which is the body of a email form.

```
<input name="bodyEmail" style="width: 460px; height: 500px; " type="text" />
```

I would like to have a big input, and start writting from the top-left part. Whid this piece of code I start just in the centre, but the width and height are the propper ones.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might want a **[textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)** instead.

```
<textarea name="bodyEmail" rows="6" cols="60">
  The user can type multiple lines in a textarea.
  You can specify the number of rows and columns this textarea should have.
</textarea>
```